# Qt SimpleCrypt crashes: access violation

Tags: qt, crash, access-violation, crypt

I want to write a file.
At first I have to encrypt the string "Banking;k1OI<]uH|V&r" using SimpleCrypt.
SimpleCrypt's code:

```
QString SimpleCrypt::encryptToString(const QString& plaintext)
{
    QByteArray plaintextArray = plaintext.toUtf8();
    QByteArray cypher = encryptToByteArray(plaintextArray);
    QString cypherString = QString::fromLatin1(cypher.toBase64());
    return cypherString;
}
```

The crash happens at m_keyParts.isEmpty() with an access violation

```
QByteArray SimpleCrypt::encryptToByteArray(QByteArray plaintext)
{
    if (m_keyParts.isEmpty()) {
        qWarning() << "No key set.";
        m_lastError = ErrorNoKeySet;
        return QByteArray();
    }
    // [...]
    // Rest of the code
}
```

Does somebody know what to do?

Thanks in advance

### Edit

Stacktrace:

> Accessibles.exe!QVector::isEmpty() Zeile 91 C++
>   Accessibles.exe!SimpleCrypt::encryptToByteArray(QByteArray plaintext)
>   Zeile 55 C++ Accessibles.exe!SimpleCrypt::encryptToString(const
>   QString & plaintext) Zeile 118 C++ Accessibles.exe!DataStream::save()
>   Zeile 40 C++

Calling code:

```
textStream << p_simpleCrypt->encryptToString(QString("%1;%2\n").arg(bundle‌​->category).arg(bund‌​le->categoryId));
```

Comment: Can you show us your code that calls `encryptToString()` ?

Comment: Where's the stack trace?

Comment: The following calls encryptToString(): textStream << p_simpleCrypt->encryptToString(QString("%1;%2\n").arg(bundle->category).arg(bundle->categoryId));

Comment: The Stacktrace is this:
> Accessibles.exe!QVector<char>::isEmpty() Zeile 91 C++
  Accessibles.exe!SimpleCrypt::encryptToByteArray(QByteArray plaintext) Zeile 55 C++
  Accessibles.exe!SimpleCrypt::encryptToString(const QString & plaintext) Zeile 118 C++
  Accessibles.exe!DataStream::save() Zeile 40 C++

Comment: @user3874443 You can edit your question to add the stacktrace and code, it would be more readable.

Comment: @user3874443 It is hard to say with just a single line of the calling code. Anyway, with what you gave us so far, I would bet that `p_simpleCrypt` is not initialized (especially because it crashes as soon as you access a member variable).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I don't know why it didn't initialize but now it works, I just construct the class new.

Comment: @user3874443 In C and C++ pointers are not automatically initialized. You always have to do it manually.